# Get an Access token from AZURE AD using Java Springboot

Tags: spring-boot, azure, java-8, azure-active-directory

I am trying to get an access token from AZURE AD but getting an error for the below code.
my requirement is to get an access token without passing service credentials to the Microsoft login pop-up. I need to pass service credentials from my code.
I have below details of service which

1. ClientId : clientid-abcd-bcda-xxxx-bbbbc-bbbbsjhk
2. clientsecret: client-secret-xxxx-bgdj-jbkjg-dddff
3. callbackurl:https://somecalbackurl.to.access.receive.an.authorization.code
4. accesstokenUlr: https://some AccessToken Url Url
5. AuthUrl: https://somAuthUrl
6. Service AccUserName & Password

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws OAuthProblemException {       

       // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       String clientId = "c64a70a8-7794-44a6-a9b8-4f44f09e17ee";
       String clientSecret = "-DW8Q~JwYM611PR7EchiCU~HKLLqjv1ogLHvAc8O";
       String accessTokenUrl = "https://login.windows.net/f761680c-0582-4825-b245-62c1d05b6b3a/oauth2/token?resource=https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com";
       String authUrl = "https://login.windows.net/f761680c-0582-4825-b245-62c1d05b6b3a/oauth2/authorize?resource=https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com";
       String callbackUrl = "https://businesscentral.dynamics.com/";
       //String grant_type = "authorization_code";

       String encodedValue = getBase64Encoded(clientId, clientSecret);

       OAuthClient client = new OAuthClient(new URLConnectionClient());
       try {
           OAuthClientRequest request = 
                  OAuthClientRequest.tokenLocation(accessTokenUrl)
                  .setGrantType(GrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)                 
                  .setRedirectURI(callbackUrl) 
                  .setScope("Financials.ReadWrite.All user_impersonation")
                  .setCode(authUrl)
                  .buildBodyMessage();

           request.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic "+ encodedValue);
           //OAuthClientRequest.authorizationProvider(OAuthProviderType.MICROSOFT);

           OAuthJSONAccessTokenResponse token = client.accessToken(request,OAuth.HttpMethod.POST,OAuthJSONAccessTokenResponse.class);
           String finalToken=token.getAccessToken();

        System.out.println("Token-->"+finalToken);

       } catch (OAuthSystemException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block

           System.out.println(e);
           //e.printStackTrace();
       }


   }
   public static String getBase64Encoded(String id,String password) {
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((id +":"+ password).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
   }
   ```

getting below error

```
Exception in thread "main" OAuthProblemException{error='invalid_grant', description='AADSTS9002313: Invalid request. Request is malformed or invalid.
```

Trace ID: 01953507-e109-4aa4-90bd-1ead69ff5a00
Correlation ID: 9f9da815-f9c5-4a15-bcdb-73810c652cfb
Timestamp: 2023-07-11 09:48:28Z', uri='https://login.windows.net/error?code=9002313', state='null', scope='null', redirectUri='null', responseStatus=400, parameters={}}

**i am trying this approach where i can pass the Microsoft service credentials from java code so that when scheduler starts below action should be performed in sequence**

1. **Get the access token**
2. **Use that token to call the service call on azure**
3. **Retrieve the the data from azure service and update into DB**

Answer (score 0):

> my requirement is to get an access token without passing service credentials to the Microsoft login pop-up

***Use the below code to get the access token from Azure AD using Spring-boot.***

```
@GetMapping(value = "/gettoken")
public static String getToken() throws Exception {
        String url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<Your_Tenant_ID>/oauth2/token";
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

        MultiValueMap<String, String> inputMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();

        inputMap.add("grant_type", "client_credentials");
        inputMap.add("client_id", "<your_client_id>");
        inputMap.add("client_secret", "<your_client_secret>");
        inputMap.add("resource", "https://management.core.windows.net/");
        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> entity = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>(inputMap,
                headers);
        RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
        ResponseEntity<String> response = template.postForEntity(url, entity, String.class);
        JSONObject myjson = new JSONObject(response.getBody());
        String data = (String) myjson.get("access_token");
        System.out.println(data);
        String access_token = data;
        return access_token;

    }
```

Open command prompt, navigate to root folder of your application and run `mvn clean install`:

[image]

Run the application with the command `mvn spring-boot:run`:

[image]

Running on port 8080:

[image]

**Response:**

*Generating Token:*

[image]

[image]

***Refer to my [GitHub](https://github.com/PravallikaKothaveerannagari/AccessToken-Springboot) repository for the complete code.***

Comment: yes got another approach and it worked, My main concern was to avoid login window of Microsoft. here below is my approach

Answer (score 0):

Here below is my approach and its working perfectly

```
String clientId = "<your client-Id>";
String clientSecret = "<your Client- Secret>";
String accessTokenUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<Your_Tenant_ID>/oauth2/v2.0/token";

String encodedValue = getBase64Encoded(clientId, clientSecret);
OAuthClient client = new OAuthClient(new URLConnectionClient());
    try {
        OAuthClientRequest request = 
               OAuthClientRequest.tokenLocation(accessTokenUrl)                
               .setGrantType(org.apache.oltu.oauth2.common.message.types.GrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)                 
               .setScope("https://<YOUR DEFAULT SCOPE>/.default")                  
               .buildBodyMessage();         
        request.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic "+ encodedValue);
        //OAuthClientRequest.authorizationProvider(OAuthProviderType.MICROSOFT);
        
        OAuthJSONAccessTokenResponse token = client.accessToken(request,OAuth.HttpMethod.POST,OAuthJSONAccessTokenResponse.class);
        String finalToken=token.getAccessToken();
        
     System.out.println("Token-->"+finalToken);
     
    } catch (OAuthSystemException e) {
        
        
        System.out.println(e);
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
   
}
public static String getBase64Encoded(String id,String password) {
     return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((id +":"+ password).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
}
```